# Blogger Condition statement for search page

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I am using custom header picture for different pages.
I have one common header for index page & one I am going to use for search page.

Here is the code with AND condition show index page header only for index pages not for search pages.

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType!= data:blog.searchQuery'>
<div class='picheader'>
<img alt='abc' src='image url' style='width:500px;height:300px;'/>
  <br/><br/>
<div style='font-size:25px; text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;'>What we do ?</div>
Our description
</div>
</b:if>
</b:if>

<!-- Only for search page -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'>
<div class='picheader'>
<img alt='Search Page' src='image url' style='width:500px;height:300px;'/>
  <br/><br/>
<div style='font-size:25px; text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;'>Search Anything</div>
Looking for something...
</div>
</b:if>
```

But with this code, index page is okay, but index page header is also loading with search page header.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<!-- If it is an Index page -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>

  <!-- If it is search page -->
  <b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'>
    <div class='picheader'>
      <img alt='Search Page' src='image url' style='width:500px;height:300px;'/>
        <br/><br/>
      <div style='font-size:25px; text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;'>Search Anything</div>
      Looking for something...
    </div>

    <!-- If it is an Index page but not Search page -->
    <b:else/>
    <div class='picheader'>
      <img alt='abc' src='image url' style='width:500px;height:300px;'/>
        <br/><br/>
      <div style='font-size:25px; text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;'>What we do ?</div>
      Our description
    </div>
  </b:if>

</b:if>
```

The condition `data:blog.pageType != data:blog.searchQuery` will always return True (unless you search for 'index'). That is why its showing on search page too.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, that just worked so well !